# If it takes infinitely long for someone to fall in a black hole, wouldn't it evaporate first?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, time-dilation, hawking-radiation

Let's say I decide to jump into a large black hole. A distant observer never sees me enter the black hole, but he *does* see the black hole evaporate. According to this reasoning, I would then keep going, having never gone into the black hole.

This doesn't seem to be what happens, though. What is the flaw in my reasoning (unless I'm correct!)?

Comment: Beware! Here there be dragons!

Comment: @Jimself I thought so.

Comment: This has been asked twice before,though I can't find the duplicates just now. The answer, provided by a certain Gerard t'Hooft who you may have heard of before, is that you will cross the horizon before the black hole evaporates. I'll have to do more searching for the original question to recover the details.

Comment: Aha! Found it! ${}{}$